# Como passar mais de uma opção de Controller no routes.MapRoute()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho a seguinte rota:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           "Contracts",
           "Home/Contract/{contract}",
           new
           {
               controller = "Home",
               action = "Contract",
               contract = UrlParameter.Optional
           },
           new { contract = @"\w+" }
        );
```

É possível configurar essa rota para receber tanto o `controller` `Home`(como já configurado), quanto para um novo `controller` chamando `Contributor`? Basicamente um OR dentro do parâmetro `controller`.

Comment: Por que não muda a rota pra `"{controller}/Contract/{contract}",`?

Comment: @LINQ mas e o parametro controller que está dentro do metodo routes.MapRoute?

Comment: @LINQ funcionou.... eu só nao entendi porque, se eu estou declarando o controller = "Home", action = "Contract".  Se você puder me explicar porque funcionou mesmo com essa declaração eu agradeceria.

Comment: A descrição do terceiro parâmetro do método MapRoute(): `"An object that contains default value routes"`.

Quando você da um `new { controller = "Home" }` você esta dizendo que se eu não passar nenhum valor de controller na minha url, é para eu usar um valor default para aquele parâmetro, que no caso seria o seu `Home`. Caso eu passe algum parâmetro com o valor controller, eu ignoro esse valor default.

Comment: @GabrielColetta entendi, obrigado pela explicação, então só para ver se eu entendi mesmo... o que conta mesmo para montar a rota é o segundo parametro? no caso `"Home/Contract/{contract}",`?

Comment: É isso aí que o Gabriel falou. O primeiro parâmetro é o nome da rota, o segundo é o **formato** dela, o terceiro são os padrões.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas mude a declaração da rota para:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Contracts",
       "{controller}/Contract/{contract}",
       new
       {
           controller = "Home",
           action = "Contract",
           contract = UrlParameter.Optional
       },
       new { contract = @"\w+" }
    );
```